# How to loop through the records and save into the database using mvc

Tags: arrays, model-view-controller, multiple-columns

I have a table in which i have three columns ( id,studentid,courseid) in my model class i have studentid and courseid as arrays as on view they are multi select dropdownlist , Now in my create controller i want to loop through the student first and then asssign all courses which comes in courses array and then after assigning all course i need to move to next student and assign him all course

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Year_Id,Program_Id,Student_id,Module_Id,Course_Id")]Student_Assigned_courses SAC)
        {
            ViewBag.PopulatePrograms = _IEducation.PopulatePrograms();
            //ViewBag.Block_Id = new SelectList(db.Blocks, "Id", "Name");
            //ViewBag.Course_Category_Id = new SelectList(db.Courses_Category, "Id", "Category_Name");
            //ViewBag.Module_Id = new SelectList(db.Moduels, "Id", "Name");
            //ViewBag.Program_Id = new SelectList(db.Programs, "Id", "Program_Title");
            //ViewBag.Year = new SelectList(db.Years, "Id", "Name");
            //ViewBag.Course_Id = _ITeacherCoruses.PopulateCourses();
            //ViewBag.Teacher_Id = _ITeacherCoruses.PopulateTeachers();
            //ViewBag.Semester_Id = _ITeacherCoruses.PopulateSemsters();
            if (SAC.Student_id != null)
            {
               foreach(var student in SAC.Student_id)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < SAC.Course_Id.Length; i++)

                       // SAC.Course_Id = SAC.Course_Id[i] ;
                        db.StudentCoursesAssigned.Add(SAC);
                        if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
                        {
                            TempData["MessageDesignation"] = "Department Saved Successfully!";


                        }

                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(SAC);
        }
```

I gave just three columns but in reality i have five columns in my table and model class .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework.

Comment: what does it mean by home work , I raised the assistance request how to  save the records from multiselect dropdown, every work is home work !